# IIS Requests stay alive

Tags: asp.net, iis

Currently I have a problem. Some times when the user loads a page a request gets stuck in IIS (see screenshot). These request are made with AJAX.

For the user everything goes fine, he/she gets all the data and request ends with a 200 status code.

From my understanding the users page request should be stuck since IIS only handles 1 request per session when "EnableSessionState" is set to true, which it is, or am I wrong?

What do status 4096 and 1177224886 mean?

But what i really want to know is:

What is the best way to try and find the source of the problem. I already tried to use the "Failed Requests Tracing" but cant discover anything strange.

[image: Requests]

Comment: What failed request trace conditions you used to trace requests?

Comment: Used a "timeTaken" condition of 1 minute.